# Do I need to duplicate my type annotations in a subclass?

Tags: python

I have a `Base` class that defines the method `eggs_or_ham`.

Do I need to duplicate the type annotations in my subclass `Foobar` or is it enough to have them in the `Base` class?

```py
class Base:
    # ...

    @classmethod
    def eggs_or_ham(cls, eggs: List[Egg], ham: List[Ham]) -> List[str]:
        raise NotImplementedError


class Foobar(Base):

    # should I write this
    @classmethod
    def eggs_or_ham(cls, eggs: List[Egg], ham: List[Ham]) -> List[str]:
        # ...

    # or this
    @classmethod
    def eggs_or_ham(cls, eggs, ham):
        # ...
```

Comment: Probably depends on the use case - would it be helpful for client code to know `Foobar`'s method signature, or does the client code only care about `Base` because you're using lots of polymorphism? Keep in mind that type annotations are completely transparent to the interpreter, and so readability and client utility is the only thing that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to (well, should) duplicate them; `mypy`, at least, does not "inherit" type hints.

Given a simpler example,

```
from typing import List

class Base:
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls, eggs: List[str]) -> List[str]:
        return ["base"]

class Foo(Base):
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls, eggs) -> List[str]:
        return ["foo"]

print(Foo.foo([1,2,3]))
```

will type-check, because no type hint was provided for `Foo.foo`'s `eggs` parameter.

```
$ mypy tmp.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Adding the type hint back (`eggs: List[str]`) produces the expected error:

```
$ mypy tmp.py
tmp.py:15: error: List item 0 has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"
tmp.py:15: error: List item 1 has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"
tmp.py:15: error: List item 2 has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"
Found 3 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: What if the subclassed method is intended to be less restrictive of the types it accepts to allows? Is there a situation where it is a feature and not a bug?

Comment: `mypy` rejects that immediately; using `List[object]` in `Foo.foo` produces: Argument 1 of "foo" is incompatible with supertype "Base"; supertype defines the argument type as "List[str]" I *think* that's related to container types being treated as invariant by default, but I'm not sure. This is a topic for another question.